# Adding multiple conditions in a function

Tags: javascript

I want to add 2 conditions in 1 function but I'm having some problems. The code I'm using is

```
 var timeCheck = function(){
    var timePos = videoBGPlayer.currentTime; 
    if (timePos > 1){
        TweenLite.to(videoBGPlayer, 3, { marginTop: -130});
        videoBGPlayer.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeCheck, false);
    } 
};
```

What I want to achieve is that when the video timePos is 1 the video moves up and when the video timePos is 7 goes back to original position.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if `timePos` is more than 7, and only than if it's more than 1

```
 var timeCheck = function(){
    var timePos = videoBGPlayer.currentTime;

    if (timePos >= 7) {
        // move to origin position
    } else if (timePos > 1){
        TweenLite.to(videoBGPlayer, 3, { marginTop: -130});
        videoBGPlayer.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeCheck, false);
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple conditions like

```
var timeCheck = function(){
  var timePos = videoBGPlayer.currentTime;
  if (timePos < 7){
    TweenLite.to( videoBGPlayer , 3 , { marginTop: -130 }  );
    videoBGPlayer.removeEventListener('timeupdate',timeCheck,false);
  } 
  else if (timePos == 7) {
    //go back to original position.
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `if/else if` logic.

```
if (timePos == 1){
    TweenLite.to(videoBGPlayer, 3, { marginTop: -130});
    videoBGPlayer.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeCheck, false);
} 
else if( timePos == 7){
    //Move video down
}
```

You said when the video's `timePos` is 1 not greater than 1, if you leave it like this:

```
if (timePos > 1){
```

the control will never reach the `else if` because 7 is greater than 1 so if possible use the equals operator

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var timeCheck = function(){
    var timePos = videoBGPlayer.currentTime; 
    if (timePos >= 1 && timePos < 7){
        TweenLite.to(videoBGPlayer, 3, { marginTop: -130});
        videoBGPlayer.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeCheck, false);
    }else if(timePos >= 7){
       TweenLite.to(videoBGPlayer, 3, { marginTop: 0});
    } 
};
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid arrow-function arguments (parentheses around the arrow-function may help)` - error because there is no such operation as `=>`